# Why in textarea value attribute is different from JS value

Tags: javascript, css, textarea

Initially I was trying to change the look of a `textarea` when it was empty with just `CSS`. I thought this would work, but as you can see when writing something and clicking the button, the values are different. Does anyone know of a solution for doing this width `CSS` or `JS` is required? Could that be possible with an `input`??

```js
var area = document.querySelector("textarea");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var value = area.value;
  var attr_value = area.getAttribute("value");
  alert("value: " + value + "\nattr value: " + attr_value);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  background: red;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}
textarea[value=""] {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<textarea value="Here I am"></textarea>
<br>
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: textarea doesn't have a value attribute - input does - is that what you thought you were doing?

Comment: You need to access the `property` and not the `attribute`. very different things. Always prefer accessing properties an not attributes, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textarea HTML elements do not have a `value` attribute. Their value is their inner text content.

Thus, the `value` property will always fetch the correct input value.

`getAttribute("value")` will fetch the value of the textarea's `value` attribute, if you give it one. But since this attribute is non-standard on textarea elements, you ought not to use it, anyway.

:)

Comment: Correct. <input> controls DO have value attributes. <select>s do not, but <option> elements can also be given (optional) value attributes.

Comment: `<textarea>` has `value` property. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Comment: Mike, you're mistaking properties for attributes. <textarea> elements, as represented in the DOM by HTMLTextAreaElement instances, have value properties. But <textarea> tags do not have value attributes in their markup.

Comment: Yes you are right. There is not attribute like `value` from `<textarea>`. Verified here : https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea

Comment: Just to make sure: in case it was an input, this would work as expected?

Comment: Vandervals: yes, it would work if you swapped the <textarea> for say an <input type="text"> control.

Comment: Haaa. You are right. Sorry, Vandervals. There is a difference. So, even on an input control, the value property will fetch the current value, as edited by the user. But getAttribute('value') will get the original DEFAULT value as defined in the markup with the value attribute: value="Default value". So, if an input control is given a default value, then the user changes it, the value property and getAttribute('value') will return different things. Does that make sense? Sorry, wasn't thinking...

Comment: So, let me see if I get it: for inputs, at the begining attribute value and value are the same, if the user changes it, then it will only update the value, but not attribute value, correct?

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your initial question is probably to use a little js snippet, since I couldn't get it to work with `:empty` either.

http://jsfiddle.net/ciscoheat/hvo3h8vz/

```
var area = document.querySelector("textarea");

area.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if(area.value) area.classList.add('has-content');
  else area.classList.remove('has-content');
});
```